# Spring, rendering list with <c:forEach> gives error

Tags: java, spring, foreach

HTML:

```
<select name="myList" id="myList" style="width: 170px;">
    <option value="">All Items</option>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">
        <c:if test="${item != 'N/A'}">
            <option value="${item}">${item}</option>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
...
List<Item> myItemList = itemDaoImpl.getAll();
...
view.addObject("items", myItemList);
```

That is just the related part of my controller. And it gives me "error[object Object]" javascript error when I load my page and internal server error on controller call. I do not understand the reason, could you please guide me ?

Comment: Because item(guess model class) is object here, try it with what the `Item` class member(s) say `item.itemName` or `item.itemId`. Post your `Item` class so you can get detailed answer.

Comment: try model.addAttribute("item",myItemList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look at the sample of iteration,

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">
    <c:if test="${item.itemName !='N/A'}">
       <option value="${item.itemId}">${item.itemName}</option>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

You must replace (itemName, itemId) it with your class member(s).

Cheers..!

Comment: Thank you very much Vinoth! =) I've missed that part out.